# How to show 5 maximum value after joining two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

- users(uid, rollno, name)

[image: users table]

- results(rid, uid, marks)

[image: results table]

So I want to show the highest 5 marks holder with their roll no and marks like-

```
MCA-03/17   16
MCA-01/17   15
MCA-04/17   8
MCA-02/18   6
MCA-06/17   5
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT u.rollno, r.marks 
FROM users u 
JOIN results r ON r.uid = u.uid 
ORDER BY marks DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

but it is not showing the top 5 highest marks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear how your query is not working.

Comment: I added the image of the tables. I just want to show the top 5 highest marks with the roll number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the top 5 marks from results and join to users:

```
SELECT u.rollno, r.marks
FROM users u INNER JOIN (
  SELECT uid, marks 
  FROM results  
  ORDER BY marks DESC 
  LIMIT 5
) r ON r.uid = u.uid
ORDER BY marks DESC
```

Comment: It's not working. I have added the image of the tables. Please see.

Comment: Add the expected results that you want

Comment: I added the desired outputs.

Comment: MCA-04/17
8
MCA-02/18
6
MCA-06/17
5
MCA-05/18
4
MCA-01/18
4

I don't know why every time it shows like this.

Comment: Oh..It was varchar. I changed it to int and now it is working perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should join the subquery for the max  5

```
select  u.rollno, r.marks 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN result r on r.uid = u.uid 
INNER JOIN  (
SELECT  r.marks 
ORDER BY marks DESC 
LIMIT 5
) t on t.marks = r.marks
```

Comment: what do you mean with " Not working!"   ??  you have an error ? show thenexact error message ... wrong result ?  show the actual result so is possibile compare this with your expected  result